# Elasticsearch query_string and term combination doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

I've written the following query in order to search documents which `have "test" in "message" field` AND `their length is between 20 and 200` AND `none of "user*" are "admin"` AND `"user3" to "user20" are NULL` all `sorted by "date"`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "test",
            "default_field": "message"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user20": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user19": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user18": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user17": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user16": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user15": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user14": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user13": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user12": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user11": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user10": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user9": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user8": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user7": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user6": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user5": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user4": "NULL"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user3": "NULL"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "length": {
              "gte": 20,
              "lte": 200
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user1": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user2": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user3": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user4": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user5": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user6": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user7": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user8": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user9": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user10": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user11": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user12": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user13": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user14": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user15": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user16": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user17": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user18": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user19": "admin"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user20": "admin"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

without `"user3" to "user20" are NULL` condition the query works fine i.e if I erase all corresponding parts in query. However, when I add those again, I get 0 results. I'm sure I have documents meeting the criteria.

What's the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: How you defined the null value in the mapping? As you wrote in query it will work only if you set "null_value": "NULL" in the mapping. Other way you can use "exists" or "missing" queries like : "exists" : { "field" : "user20" }
Can you provide the example of document please?

Comment: "NULL" is just a string and doesn't actually mean NULL. Consider it as any string value.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.  I found only one solution: You can put the mapping of field user* to "not_analyzed". If i understand right the reason (not sure) the problem is in  the index building. When Elastic creates the index, he split up the text as key: value, where key is a word and value is the document list where this word exists. So he can't get "NULL" as word. Again i'm not sure,that this is right explanation, and don't know if in your mapping user field can be not_analyzed. If you must have the user* field as analyzed may be you can use some special analyzer or build you own.